# Oracle Linux VM on Mac (Parallels) aarch64: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: macos, gcc, arm64, oraclelinux

I am running an Oracle Linux 8.8 installation with Oracle 19C (both aarch64) on my Mac Mini (M2) under Paralles.
It runs fine.
Now I am trying to run some C programs on this platform.
I just took the C sources and compile the stuff with gnu-gcc:

---

$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/aarch64-redhat-linux/8/lto-wrapper
Target: aarch64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat. com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable- linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --disable-libmpx --enable-gnu-indirect-function --build=aarch64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-18.0.5) (GCC)

---

The whole is then bound with ld to a programme with Oracle libraries.
The finished programme says about itself:
$ file SA1
SA1: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), stripped
$
When I then try to run the program, I get the above error message.
A small "Hello World" C programme could be created and executed without any problems.
Do any of you have a tip for me where I could find the problem?
Many thanks
Jörg

Comment: Hi,
i found the solution in replacing the old "ld -r" command by the gcc-equivalent.
Cheers
Jörg